# how can i make the text size in my anchor tag the same size as the rest of the paragraph its in

Tags: html, css

I have an anchor tag inside of a paragraph tag that has 3 words in it, when it is displayed on my browser (Google Chrome) the size of the paragraph text and anchor text are the same, however when I view it on my iPhone in Safari the anchor tag text gets much smaller than the rest of the paragraph...

How can i fix this and make the anchor tag text the same size as the rest of the paragraph when viewed in mobile?

I have tried setting the anchor font size to 100% but it does not seem to work..

My code for it is the following:

```html
<div class="middlecontainer">
  <h2>A Little Background About Myself.</h2>
  
  <div class="backgroundparagraph">
    <p>I was born on September 7, 2000, in Guadalajara, Mexico, where I lived for about 13 years of my life. When I finished 6th grade, my family and I moved to Texas, where I graduated from <a class="intext-link" href="http://schools.friscoisd.org/campus/high-school/centennial/home">Centennial High School</a>      in the summer of 2019. After graduation, I went to Munich for a semester to study German in order to open the possibilty of studying business management and engineering in Germany. Then when the coronavirus pandemic hit in 2020 and we were prompted
      to stay quarantined and practice social distancing, I decided to learn code. This website is my first project towards mastering my programming skills, because developing an app has always been a dream of mine.</p>

    <img class="graduationpic" src="images/graduation.jpg" alt="graduation-img">
  </div>

  <hr>
</div>
```

Comment: Try styling the `font-size` of the `a` tag as `1em`. This will apply the font size to the same as the container element.

Comment: When doing a quick check setting `p { font-size: 2rem }` worked in chrome and safari. Font-size 100% is just "normal" size - it doesn't change anything,